# Fixing the problem of the asp.net core7 project in Plesk panel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, plesk, host

I have an asp.net core 7 project, I published the project and placed it on the host, Plesk control panel, now I see the following error in the log file of the panel, how should I fix it?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Inetpub\vhosts\riaziohoosh.ir\httpdocs>dotnet AcademyTizhoshan.dll
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10048): Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportOptions.CreateDefaultBoundListenSocket(EndPoint endpoint)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.TransportManager.BindAsync(EndPoint endPoint, ConnectionDelegate connectionDelegate, EndpointConfig endpointConfig, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_01.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.DefaultAddressStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IEnumerable1 listenOptions, AddressBindContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.BindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\Azure Devops-for-AcademyTizhoshan\AcademyTizhoshan\Program.cs:line 83
```

Comment: Show us your `Web.config` file from in-production. It looks like you're trying to run multiple concurrent ASP.NET Core applications in out-of-proc hosting mode within the same IIS Website. The solution is to either switch to in-proc hosting mode (which is better overall, imo) - or use a different port-number for out-of-proc hosting mode, whichs require changing your `Web.config` (`<system.webServer>`) or `appSettings.json` files respectively.

Comment: Also, your web-server appears to be running an old version of Windows Server 2016

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AcademyTizhoshan.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 39808D4F-2DB6-4D09-A9B8-809D09CA0C00-->

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more information. It is difficult to read and easily overlooked in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, we know the port 5000 is in using.

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use
```

We can fix it by using below code.

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5002", "https://0.0.0.0:5003");
```

Or you can use the startup command.

```
dotnet run --urls="https://localhost:5003"
```